# Bitcoin animation from The Good Wife S03E13

Tags: promotion, pop-culture-references

Is the Bitcoin-related animation that appeared in [The Good Wife S03E13](http://www.cbs.com/shows/the_good_wife/photos/80780/season-3-episode-13), quite similar to the one on [WeUseCoins](http://www.weusecoins.com/), available anywhere on the internet in full?

Comment: I've wondered about that myself.

Comment: @ripper234 It would make a nice teaser trailer if released to the Bitcoin community. A lot of people would go gaga over it ;).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-fazu1rgr9k) (YouTube) to the clip with the animation in it. I don't know if the actual animation on its own is available anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to assume the video is copyrighted. The best way would be to download the show and clip it out, if you have the skill.